# network sync a looping gstreamer videos

Tags: c++, loops, video, synchronization, gstreamer

I am trying to frame sync two looping videos over a lan. Both videos have the same length but the resolution might differ. The following code works already for the first run:

[server code](https://gist.github.com/underdoeg/7104319)

[client code](https://gist.github.com/underdoeg/7104290)

As soon as the video reaches GST_MESSAGE_EOS it starts over which is fine. But the client however will keep on reaching EOS all the time. I think this is because the servers clock is already past the clients video length.

How can I fix this. Can I somehow reset the servers base time on EOS? And if so how?

Comment: I solved the issue by adding the video length to the basetime, but then the videos are out of sync because of the time it takes inbetween looping the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different approaches, I found that manually reconnecting to the server on each video end event did the trick. See the original server and client code links in the question for my solution.